# How do I parse numeric tables from a text file using templates in Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I would like to extract a series of tables from a text file. The file looks something like the following. The table heading follows a regular pattern, and there is a blank line at the end of the table. Eventually I want the table in a Numpy array, but if I can get the lines of numeric data isolated, then converting to an array is easy.

Contents of `example.txt`:

```
lines to ignore

Table AAA

   -  ----
   1  3.5
   3  6.8
  55  9.933


more lines to ignore
more lines to ignore

Table BBB

   -  ----
   2  5.0
   5  6.8
  99  9.933

even more lines to ignore
```

(Edit: added spaces before rows in columns)

From this, I would like a list, something like:

```py
[ 
   { 'id' : 'AAA', data : [[1,3.5],[3,6.8],[5,9.933]]},
   { 'id' : 'BBB', data : [[2,5.0],[5,6.8],[99,9.933]]},
]
```

I have written plenty of one-off parsers for this, but I'd like to do something with templates based on what I've seen in the `ttp` Python package. Unfortunately for me, that package seems to be focused on networking configuration files, so none of the examples are that close to what I'm wanting to do.

If there is a better Python package to use, I'm open to suggestions.

Here is what I've started with:

```py
import ttp

template = """
<group name="table data" method="table">

Table {{ tab_name }}
{{ x1 | ROW }}

</group>
"""

lines = ''.join(open('example.txt').readlines())

parser = ttp.ttp(data=lines, template=template)
parser.parse()

res = parser.result()
print(res)
```

But this doesn't separate the tables or ignore the interspersed lines of text.

```py
In [11]: res
Out[11]:
[[{'table data': [{'x1': 'lines to ignore'},
    {'tab_name': 'AAA'},
    {'x1': '-  ----'},
    {'x1': '1  3.5'},
    {'x1': '3  6.8'},
    {'x1': '5  9.933'},
    {'x1': 'more lines to ignore'},
    {'x1': 'more lines to ignore'},
    {'tab_name': 'BBB'},
    {'x1': '-  ----'},
    {'x1': '2  5.0'},
    {'x1': '5  6.8'},
    {'x1': '99  9.933'},
    {'x1': 'even more lines to ignore'}]}]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this template

```
<group name="tables*">
Table {{ id }}

<group name="data" itemize="row">
{{ ignore("\s{1,3}") }} {{ row | ROW | exclude("---") | split("  ") }}
</group>

</group>
```

Gives this result:

```
[
    {
        "tables": [
            {
                "data": [["1", "3.5"], ["3", "6.8"], ["55", "9.933"]],
                "id": "AAA"
            },
            {
                "data": [["2", "5.0"], ["5", "6.8"], ["99", "9.933"]],
                "id": "BBB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Which looks fairly close to what was stated as a desirable result in original post.

How it works

- `{{ ignore("\s{1,3}") }} {{` - this makes sure that we only match lines that have 2-4 spaces in front of them, filtering out "lines to ignore"
- `{{ row | ROW | exclude("---") | split("  ") }}` - `ROW` regex captures entire line that has several spaces between items, `exclude("---")` filters out separator line like "-  ---", `split("  ")` - transforms matched string into a list of items
- `itemize="row"` - is a group function that combines `row` match results into a list

Hope that helps.

P.S. You can play with above template here - https://textfsm.nornir.tech/

Answer (score 0):

No need to find a package that does the job, you can use regular expression for that :

```py
import re

def isolate_tables(text: str) -> dict:
    tables = []

    lines = iter(line.strip() for line in text.split("\n"))

    while True:
        try:
            match_table_name = None
            while match_table_name is None:
                match_table_name = re.match(r"Table\s+(.+)$", next(lines))

            table_name, = match_table_name.groups()
            table_data = []

            tables.append((table_name, table_data))

            match_header = None
            while match_header is None:
                match_header = re.match(r"^[-\s]+$", next(lines))

            match_data_line = True
            while match_data_line:
                match_data_line = re.split("\s+", next(lines))
                if len(match_data_line) > 1:
                    table_data.append(match_data_line)
                else:
                    match_data_line = False
        
        except StopIteration:
            break

    return tables

isolate_tables(example)
# [('AAA', [['1', '3.5'], ['3', '6.8'], ['5', '9.933']]), ('BBB', [['2', '5.0'], ['5', '6.8'], ['99', '9.933']])]
```

Il let you adapt the output to your needs

Comment: Thanks for your answer @H4kim. Your code is similar to what I've done in the past, and it certainly is a valid approach. However, I was hoping to find an alternative that would let me define the table structure in a format that is a little easier to read.

Comment: A follow-up comment: with apraksim's answer, I was able to parse my file with ttp. That was a bit slow though, so I coded an alternative using this approach (instead of `re`, I used `str.startswith`), and that was considerably faster, roughly 20x. Just something to consider if someone is considering doing this themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help little bit:

Here I have tried to write python function using macro where I am checking the first character of line, if its digit then filter else just return False, we can ignore the that lines. But when I am trying 'AAA' getting vanish so for I am returning ''.  at the using exclude_val if its empty.

Moreover, for more cleanup you can use ttp function from [here](https://ttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Match%20Variables/Functions.html#equal).

**UPDATED**

```
import ttp


template = """
<macro>
def check_number(data):
    if data[:1].isdigit():
        return ' '.join(data.split(' ')).split()
    else:
        return ''

</macro>

<vars>
   if_D_empty=''
</vars>

<group name="TABLE.{{id}}" method="table" exclude_val="Data, if_D_empty">

Table {{ id}}

{{Data | ROW | macro("check_number")}}


</group>
"""

lines = ''.join(open('t1.txt').readlines())

parser = ttp.ttp(data=lines, template=template)
parser.parse()

res = parser.result(format='json')[0]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "TABLE": {
            "AAA": [
                {
                    "Data": [
                        "1",
                        "3.5"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Data": [
                        "3",
                        "6.8"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Data": [
                        "5",
                        "9.933"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "BBB": [
                {
                    "Data": [
                        "2",
                        "5.0"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Data": [
                        "5",
                        "6.8"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Data": [
                        "99",
                        "9.933"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Additionally, to get output as your I guess you need to manage to give tab to your table [image: LIKE], That can create [image: teamplate] ,  [image: output].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, and I'm not seeing the "AAA" label in the result. Otherwise it does look closer to what I'm wanting.

That said, this is filtering out the lines to ignore using the `contains(.)`. Unfortunately this won't work in my actual text files, as there are lots of other `.` present. I was hoping there would be a way to select only lines between starting heading and ending patterns.

Comment: Thank you R. Baraiya for your response. The code in the screen capture is getting closer to what I'm wanting. I can't modify the text file to add a tab, but it does have some spaces already. The difficulty I'm encountering now is that first column is right justified, so the number of spaces is variable (see edit of original post). Do you have any suggestion how to specify variable spaces before the data rows?

Comment: Thats best if you have spaces their. Sorry I didn't understood your difficulty part. If you want can update your question by current code and output, may be I can help.